# Python Cryptography Generate Random Keys

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, python-cryptography

I am using the python Cryptography module and I have generated private and public keys using examples from the documentation. The problem I am having is that I want to be able to generate different key pairs. Like I generate one but it is always the same one being generated every time I run it. I've tried reading through the documentation as much as I cam but cannot find any kind of solution to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Check where is the set up for seeding. Make sure you seed the algorithm always differently

Comment: I hate to ask if it might just be a simple answer, but how would you go about doing that. That seems to be the problem I'm having, I've been searching through the documentation but can't find it.

Comment: Refer your documentation and check for function 'seed' or something similar to that. Usually pass current time to this function.

Comment: What specific module are you using? Can you provide a link to the documentation and post your code?

Comment: Im using the 'Cryptography' module. website is cryptography.io, my code is pretty much identical to the rsa generation example that they give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually did that a while ago, so i'll just copy/paste my solution :)

```
import os
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
from Cryptodome import Random

def generate_keypair(bits=2048):
    random_generator = Random.new().read
    rsa_key = RSA.generate(bits, random_generator)
    return rsa_key.exportKey(), rsa_key.publickey().exportKey()
```

To genarate a random key, you have to include a random generator in RSA.generate.

---

A little more human readable:

```
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
from Cryptodome import Random

def generate_keypair(bits=2048):
    random_generator = Random.new().read
    rsa_key = RSA.generate(bits, random_generator)
    print(repr(rsa_key))
    print(repr(rsa_key.publickey()))

generate_keypair()
```

Comment: I copied and pasted exactly what you typed and I keep getting the same keys :/

Comment: Oh, im sorry, I was just not looking close enough, i just looked at the first few characters and didnt see it changes later on. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah, the `.exportKey()` makes it a little more cryptic and hard to read. But i came in handy for my program

Comment: I copied the exact code and I waited for like 5 minutes after running the program but there is not output on the terminal